# Ms Word plug-in with Java

Tags: java, .net, plugins, ms-word, add-in

I'm developing an advanced spellchecker for some language. MS Word's default spellchecker for that language is not satisfactory. So I decided to integrate my spellchecker with MS Word. Unfortunately I'm working on Java and as far as I see this is possible with Ms.Net. Is it possible to do same thing with Java or can use a my Java spellchecker as a library in MS.Net.

Thanks

Comment: You want a whole new spell-check engine for Word or you just want to add words to the existing engine?

Comment: A whole new spell-check engine. That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Does your spell checking need to be applied after you've generated your document, or can you apply your spell checking to the data you have, then produce a doc?

Comment: It will warn user during the editing. Just like the present one. But with a more detailed explanation of error and better suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's not documented way to replace Word's built in spell checker with one of your own.

You could +emulate+ Word's spell checker with your own code, but it won't be easy. Word doesn't raise any events as you navigate in a document, so you'd have to setup a timer, then check the current cursor position constantly if you wanted unrequested spelling options (otherwise, you'd have to hook into the windows mouse events to monitor for a right click, then check what word you were on and go from there.

There also won't be any easy way to highlight the misspelled word (like the red squiggly in Word now).

And finally, I don't know much about Java. Assuming you could write a DLL in java that exposes COM interfaces, you should be able to do it. But from what I know about Java, that's not possible. So you'd likely have to write a COM wrapper in .net or C, the bridge to your java code through it.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the answer. I started to write the code with C#. It seems higlighting is OK with c# but as you mentioned events is a problem to be solved. For now I'm using smart tags for the prototype.